# Trained Keras Model fails to load with load_model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have trained a Keras model with Tensorflow backend. It was saved with model.save. I now want to reload the model using model_load, however, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-235-387752c910a4>", line 1, in <module>
    load_model('MyModel.h5')

  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\models.py", line 243, in load_model
    model = model_from_config(model_config, custom_objects=custom_objects)

  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\models.py", line 317, in model_from_config
    return layer_module.deserialize(config, custom_objects=custom_objects)

  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\__init__.py", line 55, in deserialize
    printable_module_name='layer')

  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\generic_utils.py", line 144, in deserialize_keras_object
    list(custom_objects.items())))

  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\topology.py", line 2514, in from_config
    process_layer(layer_data)

  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\topology.py", line 2500, in process_layer
    custom_objects=custom_objects)

  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\__init__.py", line 55, in deserialize
    printable_module_name='layer')

  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\generic_utils.py", line 144, in deserialize_keras_object
    list(custom_objects.items())))

  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\models.py", line 1367, in from_config
    if 'class_name' not in config[0] or config[0]['class_name'] == 'Merge':

KeyError: 0
```

From what I read, there seems to be a bug in Keras when a model that was trained with an older version of Keras is loaded with a recent version. So there might be a version mismatch. However, I couldn't find a report that corresponds to my situation. Downgrading Keras or retraining is not an option.

Did anyone have this issue and maybe even found a solution? I would appreciate it a lot!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For future reference: It is an issue in the config files. Keras 2.2.4 has a fix for this:

Keras 2.2.4

@fchollet fchollet released this on Oct 3 · 79 commits to master since this release
Assets 2

This is a bugfix release, addressing two issues:

Ability to save a model when a file with the same name already exists.
Issue with loading legacy config files for the Sequential model.

So I ended up creating a new virtual environment with the most recent TF and Keras versions.